# blending colors ios

Tags: ios

I want to rectangular crop the eye from one face and paste it on another face, so that in the resulting image skin color of portion of eye blend nicely with the face color of the persons on which we are pasting eyes. I am able to crop and paste, but having problem with blending. Currently, the boundaries of the rectangular cropped eye after pasting are very much visible. I want to reduce this effect, so that the eyes nicely blend with face and resulting image won't look fake.

Comment: well, are you using core graphics? If yes, we need to see the code you've used to suggest solutions. However Core Graphics offers bledning modes that should help you

Comment: Yes, I am using core graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to do the blending in code. First, you need do create two bitmap contexts so you have the bits of your face and the bits of your new eye.

- in the overlap area only, you need to determine the outer most "skin" area by evaluating the colors of the two areas, and create a mapping of those areas in both that are "skin". you would be working from the outermost areas and work towards the center.
- for color evaluation, you should turn colors into HSV (or HCL) and look at hue and saturation.
- you will need to figure out some criteria for determining what is skin and what is eye
- once you have defined the outer area - the one NOT an eye, but skin, you will blend. The blend will use more of the original based on its distance from the center of the eye (or distance to the ellipse defining the eye. Thus initially, the outer color will be say 5% new, 95% original.
- as you get close to the eye, you will use more of the eye overlay skin color.

This should produce a really nice image. The biggest problem of course will be getting a good algorithm for separating eye from skin.

Comment: I can calculate the RGB or HSV value of a pixel. But what is the advantage of HSV over RGB.

Comment: As you mentioned, the biggest problem is separating eye from skin. Do you have any idea how to do that.

Comment: HSV makes it easier to compare pixels - to see if they are essentially the same color(H). Probably you need to threshold S because if its low the H value has little meaning. I don't have any particular domain knowledge in detecting skin, but I have to believe that if you google the topic (detect skin color, image processing how to separate eyes from skin, etc) that you will find this topic well covered. In the past I've ordered technical papers, its how I found HCL (a different color space that may be of some interest to you).

Comment: Another idea - do a histogram on the eye area, using only H values where there is a strong "S" value. If you plot this you should have a bimodal distribution - that is two clusters, one skin and one "eye". If this works, you can then assume the center one is the eye, and determine the border where eye and skin meet. I have done something like this in the past, in C, as I know of no library or tool to make it any easier. If you do this, and experiment, you can create adaptive algorithms that based on the difference in the distributions, and the sigma of each, do a pretty good job.

Comment: I found that one solution of this problem is to use poisson image editing algorithm. http://www.ctralie.com/Teaching/PoissonImageEditing/#source. I am trying to write the code for this in objective-c. If anyone can help me writing code, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just write it in C, or look for some C code someone else has written. I have to believe there is C code for this somewhere.